# Response from SOAP webservice always returns null Android studio

Tags: android, soap

Im trying to get some response from several SOAP webservices at last i tried to run a code that is a well very known example on the internet. But i realized that even this doesnt run on my project. I hardly tried to understand what the error could be but i dont know why its not working with soap.
I would really appriacate your help.

Downloaded new version of KSOAP2 and also permission for internet is given.

```
public class WEBSERVİCE extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
EditText et;
TextView txv;
String celcius="21";
String fahren;
private String NAMESPACE = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/";
private String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private String SOAP_ACTİON = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private String URL = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit?WSDL";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    txv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    et = findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
            task.execute();
        }
    });


}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        txv.setText("calculating");
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... objects) {
        return getBolum(celcius);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String o) {

        txv.setText(fahren + "F");
        super.onPostExecute(o);
    }


}

public String getBolum(String celsius) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Celcius");
    pi.setValue(celsius);
    pi.setType(double.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new 
    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHTTPTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHTTPTransport.call(SOAP_ACTİON, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
         fahren = response.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fahren;
     }
}
```

No Error Messages but the value it turns back is always "null"

EDIT:posted changed code again

Comment: Check out this example as well: http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/04/consuming-soap-web-service-in-android.html?m=1

Comment: It seems https://www.w3schools.com/Xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit this api is giving error 404. You should try another url that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with SOAP Api. The problem is your [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) class. Read the documentation for [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) first. Please do proper research before you use any code from internet. **Always** read about the components that are used snippets on internet otherwise you are going to have hard time figuring out problems.

Your AsyncTask class is declared as:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
```

Change it to

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
```

Third generic parameter in your Void which is supposed to be result type. So in your case your async task won't return any data once it is finished.

```
//CHANGE TYPE TO STRING
public String getBolum(String celsius) {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Celcius");
    pi.setValue(celsius);
    pi.setType(double.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHTTPTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHTTPTransport.call(SOAP_ACTİON, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response= (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        //RETURN RESULT
        return response.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//I forgot this line previously:
return "";

}}
```

In your async task, you need to change return type of doInBackground and paramter of onPostExecute to String:

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... objects) {
        return getBolum(celcius);     //RETURN RESULT

    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        txv.setText(result+"F");
        fahren = result;
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

It should work now.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but unfortunately it doesnt work .

Comment: I changed AsyncTask<String, Void, String> but it doesnt return something again

Comment: @jacob look at your onPostExecute(String o), your parameter name is "o" but your statement uses "fahren". Paste the onPostExecute () just as it is in my code.

Comment: Zohaib Amir I really appreciate your help thank you very much.

Comment: By the way id like to ask you if you know another SOAP webservice like this that i could use to prove im doing it correct like that in the code?

Comment: @jacob sorry, I don't know about any other soap service but I can tell that your getBolum() function needs to be changed to match soap api request.

Comment: ok thanks anyway, do i have to follow a complete different way? sadly i didnt find anything else than this way of making it.

Comment: You just need url to a different soap service